# How to move windows on Mac as in windows from keyboard?

Tags: macos

I'm an ex windows user and I loved to move windows clicking on the windows logo button and using arrows.

Is there something similar on Mac?

Comment: See the "Related" column at right for some additional questions/answers around the same topic.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Better Touch Tool** app to assign keyboard shortcuts to move windows similar to Windows style.

You can get **BTT** here: http://www.bettertouchtool.net

Here's sample setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do it without external software like [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/), [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)... and many others.

There is no keyboard shortcuts for moving windows: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236