# Window moved after wake up from sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, window-manager

When I leave my MacBook Pro idle for a while (either login or logout), it will automatically go into sleep mode. After I enter my password and wake it up from this mode, I usually see all the windows moved to a different place (usually at left top corner).

I use two external monitors and they always stay connected to my MacBook Pro.

Is there a way to keep all the windows in the same location? It's very annoying to have to adjust the windows back to the correct location every time I wake up the computer from sleep.

I'm using High Sierra 10.13.5

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have some window manager that's causing this, it might be a transient thing where the external displays disconnect and windows all collect.

There are some nice window managers that let you automate fixing things so I'll mention them in case no one can confirm this is a specific bug or steps to control for this like ejecting all the displays or preventing sleep.

- [Is there a way to exactly position a window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/303908/)
- [How to move windows on Mac as in windows from keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169569/)
- [Move windows around a desktop -- and to different desktops -- using only the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28286/5472)
- [Window management app on mac os x?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16217/)

Comment: Yeah, it is almost certainly your external monitors lagging on re-connect.